# Has an aircraft's flight ever been delayed on another planet? If so, who, what, when, where and why exactly?

Tags: spaceflight-firsts, weather, balloons, helicopter

For the benefit of future readers and our [spaceflight-firsts](/questions/tagged/spaceflight-firsts) tag:

**Question:** Has an aircraft's flight ever been delayed on another planet? If so, who issued the delay order, what spacecraft's flight was delayed, when did this happen, where on what planet, and why exactly (dust?, wind? clouds? rain (water, methane, etc.) visibility issues?)?

Comment: hint: [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/01/20/world/ingenuity-helicopter-mars-storm-scn/index.html) & [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/news/nasa-mars-ingenuity-helicopter-set-for-tricky-takeoff-with-first-flight-of-2022/)

Comment: but there are also balloons to consider